# how to predict the values at future timesteps in matlab ntstool

Tags: matlab

I have to use NAR network to train a time-series for my project. To have an idea of how time-series tool (ntstool) works in MATLAB , I used the GUI of ntstool in matlab with a dataset  containing 427  timesteps of one element. While training I used a neural network with 10 hidden layers and delay value = 5.
  Now I have following Three questions :

What does the **delay value (d) ** in the GUI means. Does it mean that while training the network assumes that each timestep value is dependent on last 'd' timesteps' values ?
  how to predict the values at future timesteps in ntstool?

Answer (score 0):

Delay value means that neural network inputs are current input value and N delay values of input signals, in your case N=5. Hope this will help you.